# How to set localStorage in javascript auto_increment?

Tags: javascript

I am auto incrementing a number from 0 - infinite (or whatever number), when a user refresh thier page, the newly incremented number goes back to default `0`, i want to set a localstorage on the increment function, so that the user wouold still have thier new number whenever they refresh the page or visit again. This is what i have tried

```
<script>
    var i = {{total_investment}};
    function increment() {
        i++;
        document.getElementById('money-generated').innerHTML = `₦` + Number(i).toLocaleString('en') + `.00`;
        localStorage.setItem("mining","mining");
    }
   
    setInterval('increment()', 6400);
</script>
```

but it does work and that is because i am doing it wrong way, i really don't know how to fix this? What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You haven't stored the value in local storage; I'd start by storing the value. Currently you set the `mining` item to the string `"mining"`. If `i` is what you want in local storage you'd want to store that, and initialize the value on the page load.

Comment: Well, in general you'd (1) read the value when the page loads and (2) write the updated value in the page logic.  I don't see where you're doing either of those things.  Though it does look like the initial value is coming from whatever `total_investment` is, so you'd need to reconcile the difference between that and the existing value in `localStorage`.

Comment: Why are you wanting to increment the counter after 6400 milliseconds?

Comment: @ScottMarcus thats just the required time to wait before incrementing the counter

Comment: Yes, I get that. But, you said you wanted the counter to increase when the page is loaded/refreshed. Why would you also want to increment it automatically after 6400 milliseconds if those things haven't happened?

Comment: No, what i meant is that i want the counter to continue from where it stoped, let say the user closes thier browser when the counter was at 103, then i want it to continue from 103, the next time they get back, not from 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments inline:

```js
// Get the element reference just once
const money = document.getElementById('money-generated');

// Whatever total_investment is, it needs to be converted to a number
// Prepending a + to it, does that. You must retrieve the last stored
// value in localStorage first and, if it's not there, then use your
// desired value.
var i =  localStorage.getItem("counter") || +{{total_investment}};

function increment() {
  i++;
  money.textContent = `₦` + i.toLocaleString('en') + `.00`;
  localStorage.setItem("counter",i);
}
 
// If you want the counter to continue where it left off,
// you shouln't set it to 64000, you should set it to the 
// last counter
setInterval(increment, i);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is woking now!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value in localStorage and get it from localStorage to initialize the i variable.

```js
var num = localStorage.getItem("aNumber");
var i = parseInt( num != null ? num : 0);

function increment() {
  i++;
  console.log(i);
  localStorage.setItem("aNumber", i);
}
   
setInterval('increment()', 6400);
```

Comment: i want the `i` to be `{{total_investment}}` not `parseInt( num != null ? num : 0);` how can i do that

Comment: I just shown you an example. You need to modify your code according your needs. To use the `total_investment` variable i need to know where it gets set and how you are getting it.

Comment: you can set the value of `total_investment` variable to the value u are getting from localStorage. As a result, even if the page gets reloaded, `total_investment` value will be set to the last value before reload.